# How do I typecheck a temporary variable when using .filter method in Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typechecking

A simple question, that I am having some issues

I have a simple method

```
function doSomethin()
{
 const getSomeVariableFromAFunction = getSomeFromFunction.filter(foo => foo.id === 
 bar.id).map(foo =>foo.virtenv).sort();  

}
```

How do I typecheck that foo is of type Foo?

I tried

```
 const getSomeVariableFromAFunction = getSomeFromFunction.filter({foo:Foo} => foo.id === 
 bar.id).map(foo =>foo.virtenv).sort();
```

But this does not seem to work.

Comment: Do you want to actually check whether the elements are of type Foo (and potentially skip those which are not) and then use the fact or do you just want to state that they are of that type?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review the guidelines for [ask], and consider modifying the code here to be a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/N527dm), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing (with no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values). This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case. Good luck!